# Sum from lookup or whatever works

Tags: google-sheets, sum, lookup, gs-vlookup

I'm wanting to sum a column from a certain point to another certain point which is dictated by the user and a drop-down box. Awkward to explain, I think best to view [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wI3DhjmqTWS69Vf6dx8RIF-jG4CIRJKhxL91spg4Oo0/edit?usp=sharing).

Something along the lines of this is my thought process:

```
 SUM(   
   VLOOKUP(CURRENT LEVEL CELL,      
         VLOOKUP(DROP DOWN BOX VALUE,NAMED RANGE 'RARITY',COLUMN 2,FALSE) , COLUMN 2, FALSE)    
   :VLOOKUP(DESIREDLEVEL CELL,      
         VLOOKUP(DROP DOWN BOX VALUE,NAMED RANGE 'RARITY',COLUMN2,FALSE) , COLUMN 2, FALSE)     
     )
```

Which would be:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(F11,VLOOKUP(F10,rarity,2,FALSE),2,FALSE):VLOOKUP(F12,VLOOKUP(F10,rarity,2,FALSE),2,FALSE))
```

However, that just gives me errors:

> VLOOKUP evaluates to an out-of-bounds range

so I can't even see if it would be summing all the values between those two points or just those two points themselves.

Essentially I'm trying to get the first VLOOKUP's range, to be a VLOOKUP of the drop-down box. Assuming we can get that working somehow, I then want it to sum the values from the first VLOOKUP's end cell, to the VLOOKUP after the : found cell.

Is there a way to have the result of a VLOOKUP set as the named range?

Ie, `vlookup2` returns "rare", `vlookup1` uses `vlookup2`'s result as the named range;

```
=vlookup1(A1, vlookup2 result, column, false)
```

**TL:DR**

=vlookup(X, one of multiple named ranges dictated by what is in the drop down box, 2, false)

[image: Example re SO Q51404833]

Comment: Exp= amount of points to achieve column 1 rank. ie, for a common to go from level 0 to level 1, they would need to accrue 10 points, however, to complete their transition from rank 0 to rank 1, they would have to pay a fee of 5 and then be awarded rank 1.
i want to have a calculator that allows you to input your "character" name int he drop down menu, enter your current rank, and your desired rank, and it will tell you the total amount of exp required to go from your current rank to your desired rank, as well as the costs associated with such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNTESTED

Please try in F13:

```
 =sum(offset(index(indirect(Vlookup(F10,Rarity,2,0)),,2),F11,,F12+1-F11))
```

and in F14:

```
=sum(offset(index(indirect(Vlookup(F10,Rarity,2,0)),,2),F11,1,F12+1-F11))
```

I suspect there is scope for simplification but your well organised Sheets is set up in a different style to how I would have so is not "instinctive" for me.

Comment: simple, effective, and EXACTLY what I needed. You, sir, are a legend.
There will be a bit more involved int he ends result based off additional things I Need not shown int eh example sheet, but this part of the formula was the only part I've been having issues with and so I salute you, sir!
So essentially to be able to use the result of a vlookup as a "named range" in the formula, it needs to be indexed and used indirectly?
Genius

Comment: Thanks, I actually I thought I had set that as the answer to that post, guess not. Cheers for the reminder.

Comment: A powershell wizard, his IRL job is databases and PowerShell scripting.